# Hyperledger Fabric: CouchDB doesn't show the worldstate of a channel

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

The HLF Version I use is 2.2

I set up my own network consisting of 3 Orgs, 1 Orderer and 2 Channels. The network is set up and I can call Chaincode Functions responding with 200. So far, so good. The problem is I don't see the worldstate in CouchDB. I think it's related due to the fact the chaincode is not instantiated properly or at all

When I call:

```
peer chaincode list --instantiated -C examplechannel
```

It doesn't return anything. But if I try to set the flag `--isInit` on the first Invoke.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 -C examplechannel -n example --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --isInit -c '{"function":"instantiate","Args":[]}'
```

The response is:

```
chaincode 'example' does not require initialization but called as init
```

When I try to instantiate the Chaincode by:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -C examplechannel -n example -v 1 -c '{"function":"instantiate","Args":[]}'
```

I get the response:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg Channel 'examplechannel' has been migrated to the new lifecycle, LSCC is now read-only
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is  difference in the chaincode installation from Fabric version 2.0 when compare to previous version. Please refer below documentation for more details regarding new chaincode lifecycle

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html

Comment: I have added the flag `--init-required` where necessary. Now the invoke call works with the flag `--isInit`.  And CouchDB create a Database with the name channelname_contractname. But there is atleast one problem. When I call a second invoke without `isInit` like it should be, i get the response `Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:" invalid invocation: chaincode 'example' has not been initialized for this version, must call as init first"`. And the database channelname_contractname wont show any entries. Despite the init functions gets called.